# Read shapefile as a numpy array

Tags: shapefile, gdal, geotiff-tiff, ogr

Is it possible to read a `shapefile` with `ogr` as a `numpy array`, in order to use it as a mask to filter out a `geotiff` image?

What I would like to obtain is a `numpy array` from the `layer` below:

```py
from osgeo import ogr

map = ogr.Open('file.shp')
layer = map.GetLayer()
```

When I rasterize the `shapefile` using `gdal_rasterize` (into `tif`), I cannot find the correct resolution for the obtained raster that matches the `resolution` of my `geotiff` file.

**Note**: The `shapefile` I'm trying to read contains around 6K `features` with 5 `fields`, among them is the `area_ha`.

---

`gdal file.tif` (a subset of a `Sentinel-1 SAR` image):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: preimage.tif
Size is 9146, 11277
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (97.254882569202280,17.422529922059596)
Pixel Size = (0.000089831528412,-0.000089831528412)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=preimage
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  97.2548826,  17.4225299) ( 97d15'17.58"E, 17d25'21.11"N)
Lower Left  (  97.2548826,  16.4094998) ( 97d15'17.58"E, 16d24'34.20"N)
Upper Right (  98.0764817,  17.4225299) ( 98d 4'35.33"E, 17d25'21.11"N)
Lower Right (  98.0764817,  16.4094998) ( 98d 4'35.33"E, 16d24'34.20"N)
Center      (  97.6656821,  16.9160148) ( 97d39'56.46"E, 16d54'57.65"N)
Band 1 Block=9146x11277 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

`ogrinfo map.shp`:

```
INFO: Open of `ST20150315_Preflood.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: ST20150315_Preflood (Polygon)
```

Comment: You could always mask the geotiff with the shapefile first (`gdalwarp -cutline shapefile.shp -crop_to_cutline input.tif output.tif`) and then read it as a numpy array, rendering all areas outside the mask to be `No Data` values.

Comment: @Luke How do you get an array of the coordinates with outh looping through each feature? Is something like `ds.ReadAsArray()` possible for shapefiles?

Comment: @Marcelo rasterize the shapefile, then `ds.ReadAsArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to mask out the `raster` using the `shapefile` on `Sentinel-1 toolbox` (or `SNAP`, which is the tool I'm using for the rest of the process so I will stick to it, even if I can confirm that the solution proposed by @Kersten works).

1. `Vector` > `Import` > `ESRI Shapefile`.
2. `Raster` > `Band Maths`: expression = `band_1 && vector_mask` (be sure to uncheck `virtual` to include the created band in the created product afterwards).
3. `File` > `Export` > `GeoTiff`.